# Usage of でも+ ておくんだった in this sentence?

Tags: reading-comprehension

[image]
Then he adds this:

[image]

The story: Recently the character broke up with his lover. However, he is starting to regret it. Because his lover was very skilled/attentive, etc in the first pic he wonders if it was really love or not? He can't decide it for himself.

Then I'm a bit stumbled on the second pic.

I'm a bit stumbled on how to take this sentence.  It seems おくんだった is used akin to べきだった? I should have?

"If this is the case, I should have maintained even one honest relationship?"

Then he seems to add いつもテキトーに付き合ってきたツケが which I take that "the pretext is that I always had half hassed relationships until now"

Comment: What he has added last reads: いつもテキトー**に**付き合って**また**ツケが・・・

Comment: 検索くらいしとくんだったな [Could there be an 'invisible' "should" in this sentence? 携帯番号交換しとくんだったな](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/30188/) - JK, hope this helps :)

Comment: I read that wrong too. It is 付き合って**きた**

Comment: What is ツケ　here exactly?

Comment: Please read [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/14019/10627) to "What does 「つけ」 mean?". In this case, it's a figurative way of saying that "he's paying now for what he's done in the past". Also the [Jisho.org entry](https://jisho.org/word/%E4%BB%98%E3%81%91) for reference.

Answer (score 2):

でもしておくんだった is a combination of three elements that work independently.

- でも is "～ or something". ちゃんとした恋愛のひとつでも translates to "(maybe) just one proper romance or something".

  - [The use of でも and ででも in this sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13463/5010)
  - [Meaning of でも or ちょうだい in テレビでも見てちょうだい](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/42204/5010)
- -ておく is a subsidiary verb that means "to do something in preparation / in advance / for a future benefit". You're probably already familiar with this.
- -んだった/-のだった is a set phrase to express "I should have done ～".

  - [〜んだった to express regret?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/43117/5010)
  - [Could there be an 'invisible' "should" in this sentence? 携帯番号交換しとくんだったな](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/30188/5010)
  - [（来る）んだったなって = should have (come)?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/49149/5010)

Comment: I see. But is he expressing regret about his current relationship or the ones before this? Also I'm not quite sure how to make of ツケ.

Basically my reading is akin to "I wish I had a proper romance  before this so I could understand if this is love or not"

Comment: @Kawase_K Please read [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/14019/10627) to "What does 「つけ」 mean?". In this case, it's a figurative way of saying that "he's paying now for what he's done in the past". Also the [Jisho.org entry](https://jisho.org/word/%E4%BB%98%E3%81%91) for reference.

Comment: @Kawase_K Your reading is correct. He is regretting that his past relationships were not serious or proper. ツケ is a psychological "debt" you eventually have to pay off. This ツケが is part of the idiom ツケが回る, which means something like "time has come to 'pay the price'".